# fwrite() error, operation not permitted

Tags: php, sockets

Basically, my code should work because it works when I run the website locally. Though, when I upload it to the dedicated server, it will show these errors:

> Notice: fwrite(): send of 15 bytes failed with errno=1 Operation not permitted 
>   in /home/advancegzw/www/folder/include/SampQueryAPI.php on line 72
>
> Notice: fwrite(): send of 15 bytes failed with errno=1 Operation not
>   permitted in /home/advancegzw/www/folder/include/SampQueryAPI.php on
>   line 72
>
> Notice: fwrite(): send of 15 bytes failed with errno=1 Operation not
>   permitted in /home/advancegzw/www/folder/include/SampQueryAPI.php on
>   line 72

Line 72 is fwrite() obviously:

```
fwrite($this->rSocket, $sPacket);
```

Is there a possibility that the hosting company blocked outgoing UDP? Or is there another cause?

Comment: possible duplicate of [fwrite() not permitted, but phpinfo() says it should be](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12152706/fwrite-not-permitted-but-phpinfo-says-it-should-be)

Comment: I saw this question and it didn't help me.

Comment: did you run phpinfo()

Comment: Yes, the settings are fine as I went through them all, comparing to the local phpinfo().

Comment: Try contacting your provider